# make execution stops, exe file is not yet generated

Tags: makefile, pthreads

In this scenario, two Makefiles are involved:

- Makefile1 has implemented a pthread to generate a exe file
- Make file2 uses this file through a rule called exe

Makefile2 tries to use the exe file before this has been generated from Makefile1. Therefore I receive the following error:

> "make: *** No rule to make target `../obj/test.exe', needed by 'exe'. Stop."

What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a Makefile for every task.

Use one Makefile with two targets and make one a dependency of the other